# Does the number of warnings in project has anything to do with speed of that application?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Our project is having a lot of warnings, will that be having any impact on the speed of the application?

Comment: You are talking about compilation warnings, right? Not runtime log output?

Comment: Yes, its compile time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that there is a warning does not affect application runtime performance (it only exists at compile time).

What the warning is trying to tell you might point at some problem, though, and some of those problems may have an impact on performance (or worse: correctness).

For example, "assignment to unused variable" could indicate that you are doing a calculation that does not need to be done. "Call to deprecated method" may mean that you are not using a replacement method with improved performance.

Comment: So these warnings won't be occupying any memory space while loading that particular file?

Comment: No. They are only produced during compilation and not stored in the application binaries.